# Very simple model of water gravity flow between two vessels fails when vessel is overfilled. How to add constraints to the model?

Tags: simulation, modelica, openmodelica

a very simple model, 4 variables vs. 4 equations! for water flow from vessel 1 to vessel 2 works quite well.
But when vessel 2 gets full, the flow should stop and the pressure in vessel 2 shall become equal to that in vessel 1 (physics!).
If I add this constraint to the model, the simulation fails at exactly this time point.

```modelica
model TestOverflow
// two vessels are connected together with an opening on the bottom(e.g. pipe)
// the water shall flow by gravity from vessel 1 to vessel 2 until vessel 2 is fully filled
parameter Real HMax1(unit="m")=3; // height of vessel 1
parameter Real HMax2(unit="m")=1; // hright ov vessel 2
parameter Real A(unit="m2")=1; // cross section of vessels is equal to 1m2
constant Real rho(unit="kg/m3")=1000;
constant Real g(unit="m/s2")=9.81; // gravity
constant Real R=1.2; // flow resistance between two vessels

Real p1(unit="Pa"), p2(unit="Pa"); // pressure in vessel 1 and vessel 2
Real Q1(unit="kg/s"), Q2(unit="kg/s"); // mass flow into vessel 1,  vessel 2

initial equation
  p1=3*rho*g; // vessel 1 has 3 meter water level
  p2=0; // vessel 2 is empty
  
equation
Q1=-1/R * sqrt(2*rho*max(0,p1-p2)); // mass flow rate depends on the pressure difference and R=the flow resistance
// the flow shall stop when p1=p2 or less, so max(0,)

Q2=-Q1;  // conservation law
**if p2<HMax2 * rho * g then  // normal flow**
  Q1=A * der(p1) / g; // flow into vessel 1 increases the level = pressure/rho/g
  Q2=A * der(p2) / g;
**else // vessel 2 is full, no flow, pressure p2 shall then become equal to p1!!! HOW TO REACH THIS???
  p2=p1;
  Q1=0;
end if;
**
end TestOverflow;
```

Physically expect that if vessel 2 is full (p2=HMax2*rho*g) then the simulation shall just continue with a trivial solution of steady state: no flow, pressures are equalized.

So try to set p2 to p1 and flow to 0, if vessel 2 is full:
Q1=0;
p2=p1;

Without this additional constraint the model works well, except that the vessel 2 gets overfilled.
What is wrong with the model?

Thanks a lot!

Error code:
Simulation process failed. Exited with code 0xffffffffffffffff.
Error solving nonlinear system 8 at time 0.198323
nonlinear system 8 fails: at t=0.198323
[1] Real der(p2)(start=0, nominal=1)
Homotopy solver total pivot: Matrix (nearly) singular at time 0.198323.
under-determined linear system not solvable!
Homotopy solver total pivot: Matrix (nearly) singular at time 0.198323.
under-determined linear system not solvable!
Homotopy solver total pivot: Matrix (nearly) singular at time 0.198323.
under-determined linear system not solvable!
Error solving nonlinear system 8 at time 0.198323

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution by myself!

the key is to do
when p2>pMax then
reinit(p2,p1); //
end when;